# Как получить из JSON значение по ключу?

Tags: python, json

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":837802896,
"message":{"message_id":607,
"from":{"id":825378476,"is_bot":false,
"first_name":"\u041d\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430",
"last_name":"\u041a\u043e\u0434\u044b\u043c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439",
"username":"Nikita081205","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":825378476,
"first_name":"\u041d\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430",
"last_name":"\u041a\u043e\u0434\u044b\u043c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439",
"username":"Nikita081205",
"type":"private"},"date":1574075561,
"text":"dfgdfgdfg"}}]}
```

Отсюда нужно найти `update_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import json
json_str = """
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":837802896,
"message":{"message_id":607,
"from":{"id":825378476,"is_bot":false,
"first_name":"\u041d\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430",
"last_name":"\u041a\u043e\u0434\u044b\u043c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439",
"username":"Nikita081205","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":825378476,
"first_name":"\u041d\u0438\u043a\u0438\u0442\u0430",
"last_name":"\u041a\u043e\u0434\u044b\u043c\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439",
"username":"Nikita081205",
"type":"private"},"date":1574075561,
"text":"dfgdfgdfg"}}]}
"""
jsondict = json.loads(json_str)

print(jsondict.get("result")[0].get("update_id"))
```